# Nuxt - composition api and watchers

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to watch for some warnings in my component

```
import VueCompositionApi, { watch } from '@vue/composition-api';
import useWarning from '@composables/warnings';

Vue.use(VueCompositionApi);

setup () {

    const { activeWarnings } = useWarning();

     watch(activeWarnings, () => {
      
        console.log('called inside on update')
    });

    }
```

In my composition function I just push into the reactive array to simulate warning.

```
import { reactive } from '@vue/composition-api';

export default function useWarnings () {

  const activeWarnings = reactive([]);

  setInterval(() => {
    fakeWarning();
  }, 3000);


  function fakeWarning () {
    activeWarnings.push({
      type: 'severe',
      errorCode: 0,
      errorLevel: 'red',
    
    }
);
  }
 return { activeWarnings };
```

Does this not work in Vue 2 at all? Is there a workaround? activeWarnings does update in my component - I see the array filling up but this watcher is never called.

I am using https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `activeWarnings` is an array you should add `immediate:true` option :

```
 const { activeWarnings } = useWarning();

     watch(activeWarnings, () => {
      
        console.log('called inside on update')
    },{
     immediate:true
    });
```

or

```
 const { activeWarnings } = useWarning();

     watch(()=>activeWarnings, () => {
      
        console.log('called inside on update')
    },{
     immediate:true
    });
```

But i recommend the following syntax :

```
import { reactive,toRef } from '@vue/composition-api';

export default function useWarnings () {

  const state= reactive({activeWarnings :[]});

  setInterval(() => {
    fakeWarning();
  }, 3000);


  function fakeWarning () {
   state.activeWarnings.push({
      type: 'severe',
      errorCode: 0,
      errorLevel: 'red',
    
    }
);
  }
 return { activeWarnings : toRef(state,'activeWarnings')};
```

then :

```
 const { activeWarnings } = useWarning();

     watch(activeWarnings, () => {

        console.log('called inside on update')
    },{
     immediate:true
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  this works - interestingly Tony posted this https://codesandbox.io/s/troubleshooting-array-insertion-with-composition-api-42vd6 which is exactly what I had.